# Docker containers facing curl: (60) SSL certificate error after using WSL2

Tags: linux, docker, curl

I haven't had any problem before using the WSL2 based engine in Windows 10 Pro.
when I have changed, not just the time is always set to Greenwich (when I create a new container) but also even if I set it to my current timezone, I would still get the curl: (60) SSL certificate problem error.
This is not similar to other curl: (60) SSL certificate problems because it could work without any issues.

even for a simple `curl https://www.github.com`, I would get the same results.

```
curl -v https://www.github.com
Trying 140.82.121.3:443...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to www.github.com (140.82.121.3) port 443 (#0)
ALPN, offering h2
ALPN, offering http/1.1
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate 
chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: from the output you've shared the issue is that you are using a self signed certificate, which will always fail to be verified, unless you add your custom root CA to the trusted CA's in the system. on way to bypass this issue would be using curl with the `-k` flag, which will intructed curl to ignore the verification of the certificate.

Comment: That's right. -k allows to execute insecure connection. This solution may not work when you want to install packages where their certificates are necessary to be verified.
do you know how to return back this self-signed certificate back to normal ?

Comment: I have added a new question followed by this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690642/launch-webapp-in-windows-10-from-docker-container-inside-wsl2-without-docker-fo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem relates to firewall of my Antivirus. Everything worked when I have exited the antivirus.